# How can I use "+" in query string

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring ibatis in my project.

I want use "+" character in my query.

```
<select id="test.testQuery" remapResults="true" parameterClass="common.util.Parameter" resultClass="common.util.Parameter">
        SELECT A + B + C FROM TABLE
</select>
```

this is my test query.
When I using this query, error occured :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC-8015:Missing right parenthesis.   
SELECT A B C FROM TABLE
```

"+" is disappeared.
How can I use "+" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Spring, but no one else has responded so I'll chime in:

The '+' is generally converted to a space when passed in a URL - looks like that is what is happening to you. I would guess that Spring has some kind encoding function to convert a plain text query into one that can be passed in a URL.

Standard URL converting replaces the + with %2B so you could try that.  But if there is a Spring encoding function that would be best because you are bound to run into other characters that get lost/changed when passed along.

I found this, but don't know if relevant:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html

Comment: @user2549278 In other way you can escape string.